# Where does out-of-process MSXML IXMLDOMDocument::save save?

Tags: xml, com, msxml, ixmldomdocument

Where does MSXML IXMLDOMDocument::save save? I mean when it's called with a file name argument.

```
CComPtr< IXMLDOMDocument > doc;
p->get_doc( &doc );
doc->save( CComVariant( L"C:\\pathto\\mydoc.xml" ) );
```

Where will "C:\pathto\mydoc.xml" be?

Consider that the XMLDOMDocument is out of process, in this case located on a different physical machine. Will it save it to "C:..." of the calling machine, or the server hosting the COM object?

Comment: You're expected to change that to the real location where you want to save to, e.g., L"C:\\Documents and Settings\\Owner\\My Documents\\Some Document.xml".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It will be at the location you give it on your local system. The `save` function interprets its argument as a path and file name if you give it a string, so that's the file that the object saves its contents into. The *file* doesn't need to exist beforehand, but the *directories* should.

In addition to strings, the `save` function can also accept certain other types of arguments, including "an ASP Response object, an XML document object, or a custom object that supports persistence." See [the documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms753769.aspx) for details.

Comment: Let's say the code snippet is running on PC1 and doc is pointing to a COM object which is on PC2, what is the "local system"? The one on PC1 or the one on PC2?

Comment: Good. Then it's because the *code* is running on PC2. The object on PC1 is just a stub that forwards all its method calls to the remote computer. When the code on PC2 interprets the path, it sees it as a local path. To save the file on PC1, you'd need an object created on PC1, one that implements something like IPersistFile. Give that to the `save` method, and the data will be transferred over the wire.

Comment: Looks like we have an answer. "What happened when you tried it out?" "It saved to the local PC". Q.E.D.